# Event pattern from cloudwatch doesn't give private IP or hostname to SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, amazon-cloudwatch, knife

I am trying to remove dead nodes from chef server so am trying the following steps:

1. trigger an event from cloudwatch on instance termination
2. push the following events pattern to SQS:

   {
     "source": [
       "aws.ec2"
     ],
     "detail-type": [
       "EC2 Instance State-change Notification"
     ],
     "detail": {
       "state": [
         "terminated"
       ]
     }
   }
3. Reading the message, getting intance-id, but to remove instance from chef-server, private IP or hostname is needed which is not given by event pattern

Any suggestion?